# Cron run Nodejs Not working

Tags: node.js, centos, promise, cron

I need to run a sh script `send.sh` as content shown below:

```
node send.js -q 8435924032 >> send.log
```

If I run it with crontab as `*/2 * * * * /home/app/send.sh`
nothing is outputed.

And there is a mail which shows an error thrown by the cron process:

```
ReferenceError: Promise is not defined
    at requestURL (/home/app/getData.js:34:16)
    at Object.getData (/home/app/getData.js:15:18)
    at /home/app/send.js:173:41
    ...
```

However it gives me correct output and NO ERROR when I directly run `sh send.sh`

Can someone helps? I want to run the program every two minutes.
I tried PM2 but such cron feature is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you check the user root node.js version?

Crontab runs shell script as root by default, that means it's using the root user node.js instead of the node version which you are using to run the script.

Promise is not supported in older version of node.js.

If you have root privilege, you can check root user node.js version by,

```
$sudo su
$node -v
```

or, in your node.js script,

```
console.log(process.versions); //which contains running node version
```

Comment: Could you show me how to check the user root node version?

Comment: if you have root privilege, try this.

Comment: @@ what a magic, `node -v` gives me `v6.6.0`. But `sudo su  node -v` gives me `v0.10.42`

Comment: Just install node.js v6.x under root account

Answer (score 0):

Make some modifications to your shell file:

**Use Absolute path to file**

```
node /<path>/<to>/<file>/send.js -q 8435924032 >> send.log
```

**Or navigate to your directory**

```
cd /<path>/<to>/<file>/;
node ./send.js -q 8435924032 >> send.log
```