# How to switch Nodejs Version of root user?

Tags: node.js, cron

I am facing a problem as [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40761197/cron-run-nodejs-not-working/), and notified that the cause may be the version of nodejs.

As shown below, the node version is fine.

```
$node -v
v7.2.0
```

But it gives me an abnormal version of the root user, which is used by crontab process.

```
$sudo su
$node -v
v0.10.42
```

I've tried `$n rm 0.10.42` or `$n 7.2.0` many times won't fix the problem

Can someone help? I want the crontab process to use the correct version of nodejs.

Comment: Why don't you just examine the path at root and find and upgrade the 0.10.42 version?

Comment: I am fresh in nodejs, can you tech me how to be done?

Comment: What OS are you running?  Assuming it's a *nix, if you log in as root, you can type "which node" and "node -v" to see where it is getting the node version from and what version it is.  If that's the older version and you have nothing else depending on that old version, you can just install a newer version in that location.

Comment: You could presumably also specify a path to the actual version of node.js that you want to run when you set up the chron task.

Comment: I am using centOS. `which node` gives me `/usr/local/bin/node`

Comment: Do you mean I should remove `/usr/local/bin/node` and reinstall nodejs?

Comment: Either that or just specify a path to your newer version of node.js in your chron task.

Comment: Or change the path for the root user to find the newer version of node first.

Comment: OK I got it~~~~

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I find out that I can simply add the correct `which node` path to $PATH.

```
$which node
/usr/local/bin/node
$sudo su
$which node
/usr/bin/node
$export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
$node -v
v7.2.0
```

Answer (score 7):

I solve the problem by removing the original node and copy an new version instead.

```
$sudo su
$node -v
v0.10.42  //old version
$which node
/usr/bin/node
$mv /usr/bin/node /usr/bin/node.bk  //rename the old node
$node -v
bash: /usr/bin/node: No such file or directory
$n bin 7.2.0  //find out the path of the new node installed
/usr/local/n/versions/node/7.2.0/bin/node
$cp /usr/local/n/versions/node/7.2.0/bin/node /usr/bin/node  //replace
$node -v
v7.2.0  //success
```

Comment: I suggest to use ln instead of cp so when you update node, your root's node would be updated too.

Comment: I can't say thank you enough. Been stuck in this for a long time, with script executing perfectly manually but not on cron. Turns out (have no idea why) cron was running an older version of nodejs. But i couldn't update it. Tried everything from n to nvm but this solved it for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
[root@localhost]# ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/bin/node
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now.

Answer (score -2):

maybe you can try to use `nvm` to manager you node version. please install `nvm` by the command `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.32.1/install.sh | bash`

try to exec `nvm install version` to install which version you want, and use `nvm use version` to choose what you want.